# Is there a way to have only one grid cell use max-content with the other stretching accordingly? (cells in the same row)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is my simplified grid layout:

[image: my grid layout]

```
#grid-container {
   grid-template-rows: minmax(42px, max-content) 350px;
   grid-template-columns: 312px 650px
}
  
#cell-left {
   grid-row: 1 / 3;
   grid-column: 1;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

#cell-top-right {
   grid-row: 1;
   grid-column: 2;
}

#cell-bottom-right {
   grid-row: 2;
   grid-column: 2 {
}
```

What I'm looking for is, when top left cell content wraps to a new line the grid will looks something like this:
[image]

But when left cell content overflows this happens instead of it becoming scrollable:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening and have the first row's height be affected solely by top left cell's content or should I not use grid display altogether?

Comment: Not unless your container has a known height.

Comment: If so.. `grid-template-rows: minmax(42px, max-content) 1fr`

Comment: @Paulie_D not exactly what I was hoping for but is the best answer I got. Would you mind posting your answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand, You can try to put fixed `height` on `#grid-container` and `1fr` for second grid row

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: minmax(42px, max-content) 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 312px 650px;
   height: 400px;
}

#cell-left {
   grid-row: 1 / 3;
   grid-column: 1;
   overflow-y: auto;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

#cell-top-right {
   grid-row: 1;
   grid-column: 2;
   min-height: 42px;
   /*max-height: calc(100vh - 350px);*/
   border: 1px solid black;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

#cell-bottom-right {
   grid-row: 2;
   grid-column: 2;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div id="cell-left">
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
  </div>
  <div id="cell-top-right">
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
    <p>top-right</p>
  </div>
  <div id="cell-bottom-right">bottom-right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want is for left cell to become scrollable and top right to stretch according to it's content

Comment: Ahh , try now pls (left cell will become scrollable when content of left cell grows over appointed height)